# Can we get process A's stack information from process B if A is started in B?

Tags: linux, memory-management, memory-address

When we run a program in GDB, we can have all the information of this program's stack. If we have two executable programs A and B, and B has some function like `system()` or `execve()` to start program A. If A starts to run from its `main()` function, is there any way we can get the information about the stack of A's `main()` function (e.g., when `main()` starts, what is the value in $ESP in a x86_32 Linux)?

Comment: As you see, it is possible. However, this generally requires kernel mode programming to do.

Comment: Yes. See [ptrace](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ptrace.2.html)

Comment: You could use gdb; it has a _slave mode_, called MI/2 or something like that, so you can control it and use all its function, including inspecting memory and all the rest.